# Triggering an event when an element is created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna call a function on `creation of new divisions` in the DOM (i.e. created dynamically thru ajax call) .I know I can use live method for triggering the function. But what `event` should I use in the `live method`? I mean which even would be triggered when a new division is dynamically created?

Comment: Add code in the Ajax response to deal with it.

Comment: @epascarello But the ajax call would be multiple times and new divisions would be added v frequently. Hence if I do this thru ajax the same code would be filled within the DOM and there are possibilities that the later added js code would affect the divisions which were added previously and that could end up chaotic.

Comment: @Rahul. You can mark the old `div`s with some attribute so you could ignore it, see my update. Showing your full code could really really help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `DOMNodeInserted` mutation event, but be aware that they are deprecated and not supported in all browsers.

Better solution would be to write a custom event like:

```
$('#container').bind('MyAddEvent', function(){
    alert('Was added');
});
```

If you want the event to be applied to new elements as well, use `on`:

```
$('#container').on('MyAddEvent', '{selector}' ,function(){
    alert('Was added');
});
```

And when you add new `<div>` (after ajax requests), Trigger that event with `trigger`:

```
...
success: function(result){
    $('#container').append(result)
    ...
    ...
    $('#container').trigger('MyAddEvent');
}
```

- Note that `live` is deprecated, `on` is the new guy.

---

If you don't control the new `div`s insertion , you can inspect the DOM on each x time for new divs:

```
function checkForChanges()
{
    var newDivs = $('#container div').filter(function(){
            return !$(this).data('old')
        });

    ... //Do what you want with those divs      

    newDivs.data('old', true); // mark the div as old.

    setTimeout(checkForChanges, 1000); // Check the DOM again within a second.
}

$(checkForChanges);
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply but the problem is I wanna use an attr from the newly added division in the function and also the division could be added anywhere and multiple times. I dont think I can use $(this) to pick that out. Is there a way to access the contents of the new division with the function?

Comment: @Rahul. You can combine between the two. Which seems to be the best solution to me.

Answer (score 2):

[Detect DOM changes with Mutation Observers](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) demos [DOM4 Mutation Observers](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutation-observers) (Webkit only, at the moment). So for now, you're quite screwed. `DOMNodeInserted` is not available in every browser, and where it is available, it is awful slow. Mutation Observers are much faster, but currently only available in Webkit.

Comment: @gdoron If thats for the upvote, I have upvoted u long back :)