# Good approch for see if something is removed from the DOM with contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, contenteditable, dom-events

I have this little snippet.

```
​<div contenteditable="true">
 <img src="/img/logo.png">
</div>
```

I need to know when the image are removed, in the real world application its much much more inside the div.

One way I can complete this is by jQuery and look at the parent for the image. The parent disappers when its removed, but is that a good approch? Maybe it exist some event that is raised?

I have created this little example 
http://jsfiddle.net/V6sdA/

Answer (score 1):

```
.bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved')
```

These are the events to check element is inserted or removed.

Bind these events on the parent element and call your function in the handler.

jsFiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/PgAJT/

Comment: `mutation events` are **deprecated**. They have very high performance impact.

Comment: It dosen't work when I add contenteditable to the container: http://jsfiddle.net/PgAJT/3/

Comment: @gdoron: They are indeed deprecated, and they also don't exist in IE < 9. However, there isn't really a viable alternative until mutation observers are widely implemented, which won't be for years.

Comment: @TimDown. You can still avoid using them with other techniques

Comment: @gdoron Such as? Polling the DOM?

Comment: @TimDown. That's one (expensive)of them... =)

Comment: @gdoron: Absolutely, I wouldn't recommend it. What would you suggest?

Comment: @TimDown Sometimes you can just trigger an event, like with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9655158/601179) question. You can combine those two methods (trigger DOM polling and disable it when something was click\focus etc'). Do you have other options? The problem with Mutation events is that  they can't be canceled, and they bubbles... evil vs evil-1 **=)**

Comment: @gdoron: No, I have no other suggestions, which is why I was interested in yours :)

Comment: @TimDown. =) The combination is the best (IMO). Though a good programmer would never need those creative solution.  `contenteditable` come on...

Comment: @PareshBalar It dosen't work either, if you remove the image by using backspace no event will be trigged. It only works when you click the button.

Comment: @SimonEdström : Backspace in the sense ? plz provide demo or more info about this

Comment: @PareshBalar If you use the keyboard to delete the image the event is not raised. Put the caret next to the image and then press Delete / Backspace and remove the image.