# How do I add elements to the DOM and then refer to those added elements in Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, live

After adding elements to page using something like this,

```
$('#blah').append('<div id="bugsbunny"></div>');
```

how can I use javascript/jquery with that added element? Would the DOM tree have to be rebuild or something? I want to do something like this:

```
$('#bugsbunny').hide();
```

How can I get this to work? Is the logic wrong or is there another way to do this?

I have considered using .on or .live but these methods require an event such as "click". My code looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
bamboo.addEventListener("load", dothisaction, false);
});

function thisHappensAtAnotherTime() {
$('#blah').append('<div id="bugsbunny"></div>');
}

function dothisaction(evt) {
     $('#bugsbunny').hide();
}
```

However, #bugsbunny doesn't disappear because it was appended after the page was loaded. What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I updated what my code looks like.

Comment: Do you wrap your code in $(document).ready() ? If no, your code works, just there's no #blah element yet

Comment: You can Use the DOM Inserted and DOM Removed Event...

WHenever you add something in DOM this Event will be fired.. and you can take appropriate action in function..

Here is the same Question and Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699597/good-approch-for-see-if-something-is-removed-from-the-dom-with-contenteditable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var rabbit;

    function thisHappensAtAnotherTime() {
        rabbit = $('<div id="bugsbunny" />');
        $('#elmer').append(rabbit);

        //no sure but i think  you can do it like:
        rabbit = $('<div id="bugsbunny" />').appendTo('#elmer');
    }

    function dothisaction(evt) {
         rabbit.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: how can I do this if rabbit is defined inside another function? See the code I updated in the question. Thanks!

Comment: updated my answer. just take the `rabbit` variable to a scope where both can see it.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be working but how can I use .css() on rabbit? `rabbit.css('width',thisvariablevalue)` does not seem to be working. Am I approaching this incorrectly? Thanks

Comment: can you state where `thisVariableValue` comes from? and what part in the code it resides?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just forgot to enclose the div html inside $(). *facepalm* Thank you so much for your help!