# Check if div exists, if not - check again until it is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have a div that is created by a plugin and **appears after the page is rendered** (always at different times).

I need to check **if this div exists**, then **execute** a set of functions. However if it **does not exist yet**, I want to **wait(check) until it appears**, then execute that set of functions.

Here is what I'm using right now:

```
var check = setInterval(function(){
  if ($('#target-div').length){
    console.log('execute set of functions')
    clearInterval(check);
  }
}, 100);
```

However, is there a way to permanently check if the div exits (like running it in the background or something) and as soon as it gets created - stop, but without `setInterval`?

Because I have multiple similar checks and it gets a total mess having to set a new/different setInterval each time.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use a [**While Loop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) - **however** a `while` loop could lock your browser and crash it. `SetIntervat` interrupts each time, allowing the user to continue interacting with the browser.

Comment: Don't use DOM polling to do this, use a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: @Fran unlikely as it would block the UI from updating.

Comment: @Fran, I doubt it will, because it requires me to increment the value (length of div in my case), but I need it to check automatically if the value has changed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - You are correct. I just noticed that as I wrote it,... updated the comment.

Comment: does the newly created div contain class or id?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so, if I understood it correct, using Mutation Observer, it's going to stay there and wait for any mutations to happen in a selected element, then execute whatever it is supposed to ?

Comment: Have a look at the JQuery Initialize plugin. It will let you know when elements, i.e. divs are added to the DOM.: https://github.com/pie6k/jquery.initialize

Comment: @Deepu yes it does contain both.

Comment: You can write oncreate event like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9655180/7357322) post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use DOM polling to do this as it's an anti-pattern. Use a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead. This is a listener which can be set to trigger when certain changes are made to the DOM, eg. child node or attribute amendments. Try this:

```js
var $div = $("#container");

new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log('.foo was appended');
}).observe($div[0], {
  childList: true
});

setTimeout(function() {
  $div.append('<div class="foo">foo</div>');
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  Appending an element in 2 seconds...
</div>
```

Note that this is a very basic example. You can tune the handler function you provide to `MutationObserver()` in any way required, as the `mutations` parameter provides a lot of information about what change just occurred.

See the MDN documentation link above for further information.